# Scroll html select down

Tags: html, angular, select, dropdown

I want to scroll a HTML select down. I'm using Angular 11. When you open the dropdown the selected option is showed in the bottom of the list and what I'm trying to achieve is showing it in the top of the list.
Already tried with scrollTop, scroll, scrollIntoView and nothing works. The closest that I got was selecting one option down, and then, select the correct one again, the problem is that always the last one is shown as selected, when the selected one is the correct one. (last picture)
Is this possible to do?

[image]

This is the code:
HTML:

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="selected"
          #dropdown (focus)="focus()">
    <option value="-1">&lt;Date&gt;</option>
    <option *ngFor="let info of dropdowninfo" value="{{info.id}}">{{info.displayname}}</option>
  </select>
```

Code:

```
@ViewChild('dropdown', { static: true }) private from: ElementRef;
dropdowninfo:[] = [];
selected: number;

ngOnInit(): void {
  // fill dropdowninfo
  //set selected
}

    focus() {
      this.dropdown.nativeElement[40].selected = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
          this.dropdown.nativeElement[30].selected = true;
        }, 10)
      }
}
```

[image]